# Multiple Line comment in .ini file

Tags: comments, ini

I am looking for a way to comment on multiple lines in `.ini` file.

For single-line comments, we use `;` or `#` in the .ini file. But how to comment on multiple lines in one go?

Like in `python` we use

```
'''Anything 
in between this 
is considered as 
comment'''
```

and `c++` we use

```
/* Anything 
in between this 
is considered as 
comment */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment blocks don't exist for `.ini` files, you will have to put a ';' or '#' for each line